# Yii2 queue info showing 0 for all params but job is getted

Tags: php, yii2, queue

I have a question about Yii2 Queue job. Here is my config part in component api/config/web.php

```
'redisNotificationsQueue' => [
            'class' => \yii\queue\redis\Queue::class,
            'as log' => \yii\queue\LogBehavior::class, //The default error log is console/runtime/logs/app.log
            'attempts' => 5, // Max number of attempts
            'ttr' => 1020,  // max TTL of process - since API call can take upto 15 minutes extra 2 minutes for the rest of processes
            'channel' => 'notifications', // Queue channel key,
            'on afterError' => function (ExecEvent $event) {
                if ($event->job instanceof SendNotifications) {
                    $event->retry = ($event->attempt < 5) && ($event->error instanceof TemporaryException);
                }
            },
        ]
```

In model I add job like this

```
$id = \Yii::$app->redisNotificationsQueue->push(new SendNotification([
                     'email' => $subscriber->email,
                ]));
```

And I'm getting id after
But when I run this command php yii queue/info to see info desk I'm getting this

```
Jobs
- waiting: 0
- delayed: 0
- reserved: 0
- done: 0
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your queue name is `redisNotificationsQueue`, so you should use `./yii redis-notifications-queue/info`. `./yii queue/info` is for component named `queue`.

Comment: You help me think on right way and I found the solution. Really thanks I was tried almost all day for nothing. There is a very poor documentation about multiple queue jobs I think. Should be example of config for cases like this.